# C++ and QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Where can I find some tutorial for creating QT applications (with C++)?

How should I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [Qt tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tutorials.html) would be the best place to start with.

If you are looking for a book, again, the official book is the best. [Here](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/books/cpp-gui-programming-with-qt-4-2nd-edition/) is a link to that.

Comment: That tutorial link is for qt 4.3. Current version is 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt nokia](http://qt.nokia.com/).
you can find information there. There are several [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/all-examples.html) and [official book](http://www.qtrac.eu/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.zip)